# Featured/Bounty question filter

Tags: feature-request

As far as I can find there is no filter option available when searching in all 'Featured' questions.

Example for myself, I'd like to look around for JavaScript and C# questions. But there is no option to filter when visiting the Featured tab?

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is to use a mini search syntax:

In the search box on the questions page (but don't actually go to the search page), type something like:

> [javascript] or [c#]

then click on Featured. An example URL:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+or+c%23?sort=featured

Comment: Could I have found this myself anywhere? I did not.. Thanks for the answer. It's not very... easy?

Answer (score 1):

Filtering on tags works if you clicked the `Featured` tab. You can click in the right bar in the Related and/or Favorite tags or enter a tag in the search field.

[this would filter featured questions on c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?sort=featured&pageSize=50)

[this would filter featured questions on Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?sort=featured&pageSize=50)

[featured question with c# or javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+or+javascript)

This also works for the other tabs:

[Unanswered questions tagged c# or javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+or+javascript?sort=unanswered&pageSize=50)